# Match many results in the same String

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the data from log file whose lines are in different format, but it is guaranteed that important information is put inside `[]`, for example:

```
[User] has [do something] on [system] at [time]
```

or

```
[system] encounters [exception] at [time]
```

If it is possible, I want write a single regular expression that get all information inside each log line, i.e. the regex has to match many resutls in the same line. For example:

- `[Admin] has [logged out] on [admin page] at [Monday 20 May, 11:00]`
  will return `Admin, logged out, admin page, Monday 20 May, 11:00`
- `[Order page] encounters [NullPointerException] at [Monday 20 May,

  11:00]` will return `OrderPage, NullPointerException, Monday 20 May, 
  11:00`

I'm working on python but answers in other languages or in pure regular expression are fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "[Admin] has [logged out] on [admin page] at [Monday 20 May, 11:00]"
>>> re.findall(r'\[([^\]]*)\]', text)
['Admin', 'logged out', 'admin page', 'Monday 20 May, 11:00']
```

Verbose:

```
>>> text = "[Order page] encounters [NullPointerException] at [Monday 20 May, 11:00]"
>>> re.findall(r'''\[            # a literal [ character (needs backslash escape)
                     (           # save following group
                       [^\]]     # match any character except literal ]
                       *         # match as many as possible of these
                     )           # end group
                    \]           # a literal ] character
''', text, flags=re.VERBOSE)
['Order page', 'NullPointerException', 'Monday 20 May, 11:00']
```

Answer (score 2):

Or as a compact perl one-liner. same regexp as *jamylak* used:

```
perl -pne '$_=join(", ",/\[([^\]]*)\]/g)."\n"'
```